# Multithreaded Matrix Multiply Help in C

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I have a Matrix multiply code that does matrix multiply by the following
Where Matrix A * Matrix B  = Matrix C

```
for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
 for(l=1;l<=k;l++) {
  for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
   C[i][j] = C[i][j] + B[l][j]*A[i][l];

 }
}
```

Now I want to turn it into multi threaded matrix multiply and my code is as follows:

I use a struct

```
struct ij
{
 int rows;
 int columns;
};
```

my method is

```
void *MultiplyByThread(void *t)
{
 struct ij *RowsAndColumns = t;
 double total=0; 
 int pos; 
 for(pos = 1;pos<k;pos++)
 {
  fprintf(stdout, "Current Total For: %10.2f",total);
  fprintf(stdout, "%d\n\n",pos);
  total += (A[RowsAndColumns->rows][pos])*(B[pos][RowsAndColumns->columns]);
 }
 D[RowsAndColumns->rows][RowsAndColumns->columns] = total;
 pthread_exit(0);

}
```

and inside my main is

```
      for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {

   struct ij *t = (struct ij *) malloc(sizeof(struct ij));
   t->rows = i;
   t->columns = j;

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t threadAttr;
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttr, MultiplyByThread, t);    
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);    

        }
      }
```

But I can't seem to get the same result as the first matrix multiply (which is correct)
can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your threading code is not threaded, in fact. You create a thread and wait for it to complete by calling the join just after calling the create. You have to create a matrix of mxn threads, launch them all, and then join them all. Apart from that, the code seems to be calculating the same as the loop. What is the exact discrepancy with the results?

Example (note, not compiled):

```
pthread_t threads[m][n]; /* Threads that will execute in parallel */
```

and then in the main:

```
 for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {

    struct ij *t = (struct ij *) malloc(sizeof(struct ij));
    t->rows = i;
    t->columns = j;

    pthread_attr_t threadAttr;
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    pthread_create(thread[i][j], &threadAttr, MultiplyByThread, t);    
    }
  }

  /* join all the threads */
  for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
       pthread_join(thread[i][j], NULL);
    }
  }
```

(more or less, just not calling `pthread_join` for each thread inside the loop).

Comment: the results don't come out the same. What do you mean by joining them all. I thought thats what i am doing. can  you give me an example?

Comment: That gave me a segmentation fault. I'm not sure why?

Comment: In addition, i don't think the threads should be double array itself. I believ ethat a thread should be single by the columns and then combined right?

Comment: Missing pass by reference in  pthread_create(&thread[i][j], &threadAttr, MultiplyByThread, t);. Should be

Comment: Kevin: You need mxn threads, one per element calculated (you can also have m threads, for example, but each one has to calculate a column). In your code you created mxn threads: matrix multiplication result is itself a matrix with mxn values, each of them calculated in one thread. I still can't see why your code is giving incorrect calculations. Could you resume what are the differences among the expected values and the ones you obtained?

Comment: I found out why. I'm retarded! I had my j and I backwards hahahaha

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. Well, those things happen. I looked for those things, but it seems I also missed them. Anyway, don't forget to take out of the loop the "join" call.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
#pragma omp for private(i, l, j)
for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
    for(l=1;l<=k;l++) {
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
            C[i][j] = C[i][j] + B[l][j]*A[i][l];
        }
    }
}
```

While Googling for the GCC compiler switch to enable OpenMP, I actually came across [this blog post](http://rajorshi.net/blog/2009/05/programming-for-multicore-introduction-openmp-gcc/) that describes what happens better than I could, and also contains a better example.

OpenMP is supported on most reasonably relevant compilers for multicore machines, see the [OpenMP web site](http://openmp.org/) for more information.